# Why do I get this warning on MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boolean, warnings, compiler-warnings

```
bool image_manager::contains_image(const std::string& filename)
{
    return this->map_.count(filename);
}
```

Now the warning I get is:

```
warning C4800: 'unsigned int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
```

However since the return type of `std::map`s count() method is:

> 1 if an element with a key equivalent to x is found, or zero otherwise.

Hence it can be used pretty much like a boolean. So why exactly do I get this warning? In C++ integers can basically be used for boolean checks right? Hence `0 == false` and `1 == true`. So why does the compiler throw me a warning? I also tried using a `static_cast` like this:

```
return static_cast<bool>(this->map_.count(filename));
```

but I'm still getting the warning.

Comment: I don't now _why_, but you can remove the warning with a check (`return map_.count(filename) != 0;`).

Comment: I guess their bool doesn't perform as well as an int.

Comment: @chris but I always thought `bool` was just an enum or a `typedef`ed `int`. Something like `enum bool { false = 0, true = 1 };` ?

Comment: It is only a warning - it is common if you have type conversions like that. Sometimes these things are useful to know.

Comment: Got banned on Google? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy.aspx

Comment: @ApprenticeHacker, It doesn't have to be, but often times it is represented as an int internally. If it's giving you that warning, I'm guessing it isn't here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there a performance warning on cast pointer to bool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847860/why-is-there-a-performance-warning-on-cast-pointer-to-bool)

Comment: @ApprenticeHacker In C99, yes. In C++, it's a full fledged type.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: In C99, `bool` is a macro for `_Bool`, which is a full-fledged type. Converting any scalar to `_Bool` yields either 0 or 1, so the same performance considerations apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, an `unsigned int` is not a `bool`, hence the warning. Try:

```
return this->map_.count(filename) > 0;
```

instead.

Comment: -1 should still be true in terms of bool. Anything not 0 is true.

Comment: @chris true in general but it depends on the particular application. Here apparently `> 0` is enough…

Comment: @chris Woops, that's odd to warn on an explicit conversion. Note that an unsigned int can't be `-1`, and `map::count` can only return 0 or 1 anyway.

Comment: True, just pointing it out as a general case. Why bother changing things on a per case basis when they offer no advantage over the general case?

Comment: @chris To save one character =)

Comment: @Simon Use the double-negative `!!` to save another character. Some MSVC users treat that as the `bool` conversion pseudo-operator because of this counterproductive warning. — at least, that's what I hear. Maybe under this version of MSVC the warning would still occur :P

Answer (score 0):

```
size_type count ( const key_type& x ) const;
```

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to
>   member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero value,
>   null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to
>   false; any other value is converted to true. A prvalue of type
>   std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of type bool; the
>   resulting value is false.

By standard program is well-formed and should works on all compilers, that support standard.

Comment: It's OK to give a warning, the standard says nothing about that. Treating warnings as errors causes any compiler to be noncompliant.

Comment: ehhmm weird fix. What he meant to say is that the standard doesn't force the compilers about what kind of warnings it should/shouldn't emit.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: with gcc sometimes you have to treat warnings as errors to be compilant.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Ah, I meant all warnings as errors — such as this one. In particular GCC is a little picky when you enable that option, but (from what I hear) MSVC will really treat *all* insignificant warnings as fatal.