# OpenCV YAML parsing bool

Tags: c++, opencv, yaml

I'm using opencv to read and write my app configuration file. 
I have a bool that i want to store there. It it saved as an int:

> camera:
>         auto_gain: 1

I try to read it the following way:

```
auto_gain=static_cast<bool>(static_cast<int>(camera["auto_gain"]));
```

but I get a warning:

> warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or
>   'false' (performance warning)

What is the correct way to parse bool in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847860/why-is-there-a-performance-warning-on-cast-pointer-to-bool), you should use:

```
auto_gain = static_cast<int>(camera["auto_gain"]) != 0;
```