# Double not (!!) operator in PHP

Tags: php, operators

What does the double *not* operator do in PHP?

For example:

```
return !! $row;
```

What would the code above do?

Comment: This is essentially the same as doing `return (bool) $row;`

Comment: I was wondering which of them is faster and we have (bool) as winner. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcnsM.png

Answer (score 330, accepted):

It's not the "double not operator", it's the **not** operator applied twice. The right `!` will result in a boolean, *regardless of the operand*. Then the left `!` will negate that boolean.

This means that for any true value (numbers other than zero, non-empty strings and arrays, etc.) you will get the boolean value `TRUE`, and for any false value (0, 0.0, `NULL`, empty strings or empty arrays) you will get the boolean value `FALSE`.

It is functionally equivalent to a cast to `boolean`:

```
return (bool)$row;
```

Comment: "double-not-operator" or "double not-operator" .. depends how you read it.

Comment: @nickf not really, "the double not operator" refers to one operator, not the act of using the not operator twice.

Comment: @Theo, It's actually one operator?   Does the interpreter consider `!!` equal to `(bool)` in this case? Or will different machine code be run depending on which one is used?

Comment: This Works for JavaScript too, 
Here's a list of [Falsy Values For Javascript](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) and heres a list of [Falsy Values For PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)

Comment: You can use as many as you want.  If there is an odd number of 'bangs' (exclamation points) it will be a NOT operation same as `!value`, and if there is an even number of bangs it will be the same as `(bool) value`.

Comment: I've known this as the "bang-bang" operator.

Answer (score 56):

It's the same (or almost the same - there might be some corner case) as casting to bool. If `$row` would cast to true, then `!! $row` is also true.

But if you want to achieve `(bool) $row`, you should probably use just that - and not some "interesting" expressions ;)

Comment: Thank's that actualy makes sense, I nevers seen something like this in other programing language.

Comment: Using `!!` is a habit remaining from programming in C(++). In C doing a cast isn't as easy as in PHP, you can get many different problems, compile warnings, a.s.o. Thus people cast to boll by using `!!`.

Comment: @nikic - It sounds strange, IMO... since `operator!` is overloadable, using it in `C++` would be dangerous. Also you cannot cast structs in C, or use `!` with them. Also if something can be negated, you're most likely able to return it from a function returning int, which pretty much makes it a boolean. Are you sure you're talking about C?

Comment: Hum, I'm no C programmer, admittedly. But I have seen some commits in software there a cast was replaced by `!!` and assumed that that's due to compiler warnings. Now I researched a little bit and found this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206564/what-is-the-performance-implication-of-converting-to-bool-in-c](Performance Warnings in VS).

Comment: I have seen !! in many C programs as a safe conversion to 1/0. (As boolean really is nothing but 0/"non zero" in C.)

Comment: @viraptor, `!!` is nothing "interesting" as you so claimed. It's all over the place from C to JavaScript.

Comment: @Pacerier hence the quotes. It's "interesting" as in - does the same thing as a cast, but uses potentially confusing syntax.

Comment: @viraptor, I mean, it's a well-known idiom across many languages. So it's not exactly confusing in any way.

Answer (score 20):

It means if `$row` has a [truthy](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) value, it will return `true`, otherwise `false`, converting to a boolean value.

Here is example expressions to boolean conversion from php docs.

```
Expression             Boolean
$x = "";               FALSE
$x = null;             FALSE
var $x;                FALSE
$x is undefined        FALSE
$x = array();          FALSE
$x = array('a', 'b');  TRUE
$x = false;            FALSE
$x = true;             TRUE
$x = 1;                TRUE
$x = 42;               TRUE
$x = 0;                FALSE
$x = -1;               TRUE
$x = "1";              TRUE
$x = "0";              FALSE
$x = "-1";             TRUE
$x = "php";            TRUE
$x = "true";           TRUE
$x = "false";          TRUE
```

Answer (score 7):

"not not" is a convenient way in many languages for understanding what truth value the language assigns to the result of any expression. For example, in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29):

```
>>> not not []
False
>>> not not [False]
True
```

It can be convenient in places where you want to reduce a complex value down to something like "is there a value at all?".

Comment: What a wretched example.  Better to show >>> not not True.
Well qualified to explain absence of a value at all, though.

Answer (score 2):

Another more human, maybe simpler, way to 'read' the not not:

- The first '!' does 2 things: 'convert' the value to boolean, then output its opposite. So it will give true if the value is a 'falsy' one.
- The second '!' is just to output the opposite of the first.

So, basically, the input value can be anything, maybe a string, but you want a boolean output, so use the first '!'. At this point, if you want TRUE when the input value is 'falsy', then stop here and just use a single '!'; otherwise if you want TRUE when the input value is 'truthy', then add another '!'.

Answer (score -1):

Lets look at

```
!$a;
```

Rather than interpreting the ! operator as as taking the

Boolean opposite of the ***value*** to its right

read

take the Boolean opposite of the ***expression*** to its right

In this case

```
$a;
```

could be an expression

so to is

```
!$a;
```

so is

```
!!$a;
```

and

```
!!!$a;
```

and so on, as each of these is a valid expression, the ! operator can be prepended to each of them.