# Is there any difference between !!$var and (bool) $var?

Tags: php, casting

Is there any differences between using `!!` or `(bool)` operators when you want to cast data types?

```
    $number = 1;

    var_dump( (bool) $number ) //true
    var_dump( !! $number ) //true
```

Comment: Actually, nopes. Both are same... :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar No internal differences too? (PHP wise)

Comment: There are... :) Lemme check it out.

Comment: There are no differences. That said, use `(bool)`. It's semantically meaningful and completely obvious in its intent. `!!` does the *same cast*, and then negates it twice for no benefit.

Comment: I'd say `(bool)` or `(boolean)` is much more readable `:)`

Comment: Comment on PHO.net that may be relevant: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#78099

Comment: Yes, It's about `PHP` not `JS` I didn't read it well :p

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double Not (!!) Operator in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127260/double-not-operator-in-php)

Comment: @WesleyMurch If you read clearly, I am not asking what is !! operator. I am asking differences between !! and (bool) operator. How is it being duplicate?

Comment: @Aristona If you read the answers on that question is will become clear to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(bool)`, as mentioned by [meagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/meagar) in the comments, is more semantically meaningful. Also, keep in mind that `(bool)` is performing one operation, while `!!` is performing two (a double-negation). The difference in performance is pretty much undetectable, but it may add up if used in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

Using '!!' makes you to doubly negate the sentence. As you are using !'s to do so, PHP will automatically cast the variable to boolean, and since you are negating the negation, the variable's value will remain the same. So, casting a variable by using '(bool)' or '!!' basically has the same effect.

Comment: 1-It's a comment not an answer. 2- it's link only answer. 3- It doesn't answer the question!

Comment: @SheikhHeera it's about `PHP`

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the bad answer