# Hide buttons if not an admin

Tags: javascript, php

What I want is something like that :

If not admin then hide some button. But if I do

```
if ($Admin == null)
   {
       echo "You are not admin"; //That works
       //So we hide the button id="New"
?>      
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('New').style.visibility = "hidden";     
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

But nothing happens. It says "You are not admin" but the button isn't hidden

I know how to hide fields by clicking buttons or checking checkbox with functions but i don't know how how to do by using a "if". 
Thanks for reading

Comment: Use document.getElementById('New').style.display = "none";

Comment: I'd advise not to just hide admin buttons but not to echo them at all

Comment: This is a bad idea.  The buttons should ideally not even be in the page, unless you're an admin user.  Never do anything like this client-side.  ^^ Ninja'd!

Comment: @SunilPachlangia: If the OP's code isn't working, that won't work either.

Comment: document.getElementById('New').style.display = "none"; doesn't work :/

My problem is much more difficult thant what i exlained. Because there are 3 kinds of admins and they have diffents authorizations. Theire are many buttons

Comment: @Hearner: And yet the main point doesn't change: Don't output the buttons when the user isn't an admin. At all. (Rather than trying to hide them with client-side code.)

Answer (score 2):

You should not just hide the button but not echo it at all.
Unless the "not admin" can change the html and get access to admin features, in other words your web page can get hacked

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to simply not output the button with the `id` `"New"` **at all**.

Very much second best:

If your code isn't working, it means one of these things:

1. The button doesn't exist yet when the script runs. Output it *later*, at the end of the page, after you've output the button.
2. The button doesn't have `id="New"` on it. Either give it an ID, or if I guess that `"New"` is the `value`, you can do `document.querySelector("input[type=button][value=New]")` rather than `document.getElementById`.

---

Irrespective of whether you output the button or hide it, it's **vital** that whatever server-side code it is that runs when the button is pressed *also* checks that the user is an admin and disregards the action, since requests can be faked. You may well already be doing that, but I thought I'd flag it up.

Answer (score -1):

Display the button if and only if the user is admin:

```
<?php if (!!$Admin) { ?>
    <!-- display the button -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using a double negative? You don't need the exclamation marks at all.

Comment: It converts $Admin to boolean.

Comment: @Styphon, kindly read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127260/double-not-operator-in-php

Comment: But doing `if ($Admin)` will give you the exact same result, if Admin is empty, null, 0 or false it won't run the code, anything else and it will. Why do you need to type cast it as a boolean?