# Laravel How to check if value exist and it is equal to 0

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel and I'm want to check if the value exist and it is equal to 1. Below is what I have tried. But it doesn't work.

```
if(isset($request['active_year'] == "1")) {
    $activeYear = 1;
    $currentActiveYear = AcademicYear::where('active_year', 1)->update(['active_year' => 0]);
  } else {
    $activeYear = 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know.

```
if(($request['active_year'] == "1") && isset($request['active_year'])) {
    $activeYear = 1;
    $currentActiveYear = AcademicYear::where('active_year', 1)->update(['active_year' => 0]);
  }
  $activeYear = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need else part define it before condition and check with `isset`

```
$activeYear = 0;
if(isset($request['active_year']) && $request['active_year'] == '1'){
    $activeYear = 1;
    $currentActiveYear = AcademicYear::where('active_year', 1)->update(['active_year' => 0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, according to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), `isset()` expects a variable. It can't evaluate expressions, as you are trying with `isset($request['active_year'] == "1")`. Secondly, this is more related to PHP itself than Laravel.

You should split the checking into two parts: first, check if the variable `$request['active_year']` exists. You can do that using `isset($request['active_year'])` or with `!!$request['active_year']`([using double-not operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127260/double-not-operator-in-php)). Then, check whether the value is equal to 1 with `$request['active_year'] == "1"`. Note that using `==` is a [loose comparison](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). If you wish to also check if the variable is of type string, you should use `===` which is a strict comparison.

Considering the above, I would write:

```
if(!!$request['active_year'] && $request['active_year'] === "1") {
    $activeYear = 1;
    $currentActiveYear = AcademicYear::where('active_year', 1)->update(['active_year' => 0]);
} else {
    $activeYear = 0;
}
```