# Warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010, visual-c++-2008

I have this problem in my code:

```
bool CBase::isNumber()
{
return (id & MID_NUMBER);
}

bool CBase::isVar()
{
return (id & MID_VARIABLE);
}

bool CBase::isSymbol()
{
return (id & MID_SYMBOL);
}
```

Comment: Did you try `return (id & MID_NUMBER) > 0;`?

Comment: id or MID_SYMBOL must be of type BOOL. which is just #define to int type in Windows. Your return value is BOOL and it is converted into bool(true or false ).

Comment: Why not !=0 instead of >0. And no, bool it not BOOL

Comment: `(id & MID_NUMBER) != 0;` is the general way to avoid the warning.

Comment: One of the warnings I usually turn off: #pragma warning(disable: 4800)

Comment: I took your title and put it into Google, several of the first results explain the warning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the performance implication of converting to bool in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206564/what-is-the-performance-implication-of-converting-to-bool-in-c)

Comment: Why not accept Marco's answer?

Answer (score 56):

FYI: Casts won't hide the warning [by design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy.aspx).

Something like

```
return (id & MID_NUMBER) != 0;
```

should clearly state "I want to check whether this value is zero or not" and let the compiler be happy

Answer (score 2):

Use the !! idiom eg

```
bool CBase::isNumber()
{
    return !!(id & MID_NUMBER);
}
```

Comment: Just to please the compiler !??

Comment: And why 2 ops instead of 1 (even if it is optimized)?

Comment: @Dieter Lücking: Non-standard workarounds are probably worse.

Comment: @deviantfan The warning itself is useless

Comment: @DieterLucking: It can not be useless as it is warning.

Comment: @Lücking: Why? Of course the compiler can generate the correct stuff without changed code, but maybe the coder has not intended a implicit cast and finds a semantic error because of the warning?

Comment: First inverts it so you get the inverse of what you actually wanted, second inverts that so you get what you actually wanted.  Useful when you have a mix of BOOL (windows), Bool (xwindows) and bool (C++)

Comment: @deviantfan : The warning is not about semantics, it is about performance, which is specious.

Comment: I give you a +1. This was useful for me, since I have this warning in templated code where I cannot compare against 0 but !! works.

Answer (score 2):

Where's the declaration of id and MID_NUMBER? Are you sure they are not windef-style BOOLs rather than (lowercase) bool's? BOOL's have been in windef for decades typedef'd as an int; they pre-date proper C++ bool's and a lot of developers still use them.