# Double Negation in C++

Tags: c++, boolean

I just came onto a project with a pretty huge code base.

I'm mostly dealing with C++ and a lot of the code they write uses double negation for their boolean logic.

```
 if (!!variable && (!!api.lookup("some-string"))) {
       do_some_stuff();
 }
```

I know these guys are intelligent programmers, it's obvious they aren't doing this by accident.

I'm no seasoned C++ expert, my only guess at why they are doing this is that they want to make absolutely positive that the value being evaluated is the actual boolean representation. So they negate it, then negate that again to get it back to its actual boolean value.

Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: check here, already asked, [Is !! a safe way to convert to bool in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206106/is-a-safe-way-to-convert-to-bool-in-c)

Comment: This topic has been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206106/is-a-safe-way-to-convert-to-bool-in-c#206122).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is !! a safe way to convert to bool in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206106/is-a-safe-way-to-convert-to-bool-in-c)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

It's a trick to convert to bool.

Comment: Exactly right, it's a common idiom in most languages where ! is the negation operator with an implicit cast to boolean

Comment: I think cast it explicitly with (bool) would be clearer, why use this tricky !!, because it is of less typing?

Comment: However, it's pointless in C++ or modern C, or where the result is only used in a boolean expression (as in the question). It was useful back when we had no `bool` type, to help avoid storing values other than `1` and `0` in boolean variables.

Comment: I agree with @baiyanhuang... surely it only decreases readability at no real gain?

Comment: @lzprgmr: explicit cast causes a ["performance warning"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy.aspx) on MSVC. Using `!!` or `!=0` solves the problem, and among the two I find the former cleaner (since it will work on a greater amount of types). Also I agree that there is no reason to use either in the code in question.

Comment: @Noldorin, I think it *improves* readability - if you know what it means, it is simple, neat and logical.

Comment: Improves? Bloody hell... give me some of whatever you're smoking.

Answer (score 78):

It's actually a very useful idiom in some contexts.  Take these macros (example from the Linux kernel).  For GCC, they're implemented as follows:

```
#define likely(cond)   (__builtin_expect(!!(cond), 1))
#define unlikely(cond) (__builtin_expect(!!(cond), 0))
```

Why do they have to do this?  GCC's `__builtin_expect` treats its parameters as `long` and not `bool`, so there needs to be some form of conversion.  Since they don't know what `cond` is when they're writing those macros, it is most general to simply use the `!!` idiom.

They could probably do the same thing by comparing against 0, but in my opinion, it's actually more straightforward to do the double-negation, since that's the closest to a cast-to-bool that C has.

This code can be used in C++ as well... it's a lowest-common-denominator thing.  If possible, do what works in both C and C++.

Comment: I think this makes a lot of sense when you think through it.  I haven't read every answer, but it seems like the conversion process isn't specified.  If we have a value with 2 bits high and'd with a value that has only one bit high, we will have a non-zero value.  Negating a non-zero value results in a boolean conversion (false if it's zero, true otherwise).  Then negating again results in a boolean that represents the original truth.

Comment: Since SO won't allow me to update my comment, I will add a fix to my mistake.   Negating an integral value results in a boolean conversion (false if it's non-zero, true otherwise).

Answer (score 53):

The coders think that it will convert the operand to bool, but because the operands of && are already implicitly converted to bool, it's utterly redundant.

Comment: Visual C++ gives a performance wanring in some cases without this trick.

Comment: I'd suppose it'd be best to just disable the warning than to work around useless warnings in the code.

Comment: Perhaps they don't realize it.  This does make perfect sense in the context of a macro though, where you could be working with integral data types that you're not aware of.  Consider objects with parenthesis operator overloaded to return integral value representing a bit field.

Answer (score 14):

Yes it is correct and no you are not missing something.  `!!` is a conversion to bool.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206106/is-a-safe-way-to-convert-to-bool-in-c) for more discussion.

Answer (score 13):

It's a technique to avoid writing (variable != 0) - i.e. to convert from whatever type it is to a bool.

IMO Code like this has no place in systems that need to be maintained - because it is not immediately readable code (hence the question in the first place).

Code must be legible - otherwise you leave a time debt legacy for the future - as it takes time to understand something that is needlessly convoluted.

Comment: My definition of a trick is something that not everyone can understand at the first reading. 

Something that needs figuring out is a trick.

Also horrible because the ! operator could be overloaded...

Comment: @orlandu63: simple typecasting is `bool(expr)`: it does the right thing and everybody understand the intent at first sight. `!!(expr)` is a double negation, which accidentally converts to bool... this is not simple.

Answer (score 9):

It side-steps a compiler warning. Try this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int foo = 5;
    bool bar = foo;
    bool baz = !!foo;
    return 0;
}
```

The 'bar' line generates a "forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)" on MSVC++, but the 'baz' line sneaks through fine.

Comment: Most commonly encountered in the Windows API itself which doesn't know about the `bool` type - everything is encoded as `0` or `1` in an `int`.

Answer (score 6):

Legacy C developers had no Boolean type, so they often `#define TRUE 1` and `#define FALSE 0` and then used arbitrary numeric data types for Boolean comparisons. Now that we have `bool`, many compilers will emit warnings when certain types of assignments and comparisons are made using a mixture of numeric types and Boolean types. These two usages will eventually collide when working with legacy code.

To work around this problem, some developers use the following Boolean identity: `!num_value` returns `bool true` if `num_value == 0`; `false` otherwise. `!!num_value` returns `bool false` if `num_value == 0`; `true` otherwise. The single negation is sufficient to convert `num_value` to `bool`; however, the double negation is necessary to restore the original sense of the Boolean expression.

This pattern is known as an *idiom*, i.e., something commonly used by people familiar with the language. Therefore, I don't see it as an anti-pattern, as much as I would `static_cast<bool>(num_value)`. The cast might very well give the correct results, but some compilers then emit a performance warning, so you still have to address that.

The other way to address this is to say, `(num_value != FALSE)`. I'm okay with that too, but all in all, `!!num_value` is far less verbose, may be clearer, and is not confusing the second time you see it.

Answer (score 4):

Is operator! overloaded?
If not, they're probably doing this to convert the variable to a bool without producing a warning. This is definitely not a standard way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

`!!` was used to cope with original C++ which did not have a boolean type (as neither did C).

---

Example Problem:

Inside `if(condition)`, the `condition` needs to evaluate to some type like `double, int, void*`, etc., but not `bool` as it does not exist yet.

Say a class existed `int256` (a 256 bit integer) and all integer conversions/casts were overloaded.

```
int256 x = foo();
if (x) ...
```

To test if `x` was "true" or non-zero, `if (x)` would convert `x` to some integer and *then* assess if that `int` was non-zero.   A typical overload of `(int) x` would return only the LSbits of `x`.  `if (x)` was then only testing the LSbits of `x`.

But C++ has the `!` operator.  An overloaded `!x` would typically evaluate all the bits of `x`.  So to get back to the non-inverted logic `if (!!x)` is used.

Ref [Did older versions of C++ use the `int` operator of a class when evaluating the condition in an `if()` statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994263/did-older-versions-of-c-use-the-int-operator-of-a-class-when-evaluating-the)

Answer (score 1):

As [Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code#248701) mentioned, it might well matter if operator overloading is in play.  Otherwise, in C/C++ it doesn't matter except if you're doing one of the following things:

- direct comparison to `true` (or in C something like a `TRUE` macro), which is almost always a bad idea.  For example:

  `if (api.lookup("some-string") == true) {...}`
- you simply want something converted to a strict 0/1 value.  In C++ an assignment to a `bool` will do this implicitly (for those things that are implicitly convertible to `bool`).  In C or if you're dealing with a non-bool variable, this is an idiom that I've seen, but I prefer the `(some_variable != 0)` variety myself.

I think in the context of a larger boolean expression it simply clutters things up.

Answer (score 1):

If *variable* is of object type, it might have a ! operator defined but no cast to bool (or worse an implicit cast to int with different semantics. Calling the ! operator twice results in a convert to bool that works even in strange cases.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an example of the **double-bang trick** (see [The Safe Bool Idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html) for more details). Here I summarize the first page of the article.

In C++ there are a number of ways to provide Boolean tests for classes.

> An obvious way is the `operator bool` conversion operator.

```
// operator bool version
class Testable {
    bool ok_;
    public:
    explicit Testable(bool b = true) : ok_(b) {}

    operator bool() const { // use bool conversion operator
      return ok_;
    }
};
```

We can test the class as thus:

```
Testable test;
if (test) {
    std::cout << "Yes, test is working!\n";
}
else { 
    std::cout << "No, test is not working!\n";
}
```

However, `operator bool` is considered unsafe because it allows nonsensical operations such as `test << 1;` or `int i = test`.

> Using `operator!` is safer because we avoid implicit conversion or overloading issues.

The implementation is trivial,

```
bool operator!() const { // use operator!
    return !ok_;
}
```

The two idiomatic ways to test `Testable` object are

```
Testable test;
if (!!test) {
    std::cout << "Yes, test is working!\n";
}
if (!test) {
    std::cout << "No, test is not working!\n";
}
```

The first version `if (!!test)` is what some people call the **double-bang trick**.

Comment: Since C++11, one can use ``explicit operator bool`` to prevent implicit conversion to other integral types.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct but, in C, pointless here -- 'if' and '&&' would treat the expression the same way without the '!!'.

The reason to do this in C++, I suppose, is that '&&' could be overloaded. But then, so could '!', so it doesn't *really* guarantee you get a bool, without looking at the code for the types of `variable` and `api.call`. Maybe someone with more C++ experience could explain; perhaps it's meant as a defense-in-depth sort of measure, not a guarantee.

Comment: The compiler would treat the values the same either way if it's only used as an operand to an `if` or `&&`, but using `!!` may help on some compilers if `if (!!(number & mask))` gets replaced with `bit triggered = !!(number & mask); if (triggered)`; on some embedded compilers with bit types, assigning e.g. 256 to a bit type will yield zero.  Without the `!!`, the apparently-safe transformation (copying the `if` condition to a variable and then branching) won't be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the programmers were thinking something like this...

!!myAnswer is boolean. In context, it should become boolean, but I just love to bang bang things to make sure, because once upon a time there was a mysterious bug that bit me, and bang bang, I killed it.