# What is the purpose of a double negative in macro definition, like (!!(expr))?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double Negation in C++ code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code)

I'm reading a code base, and find something like this:

```
#define uassert(msgid, msg, expr) (void)((!!(expr))||(uasserted(msgid, msg), 0))
```

I cannot figure out why **(!!(expr))** is used instead of a single **(expr)**. Anyway, a double negative means positive, is not it? Am I missing something?

Comment: I cannot even figure out what's the purpose of this code! ;)

Comment: Like R says, it's completely useless here.

Comment: it's redundant in this case as you yourself have correctly pointed out. Maybe it was just added to avoid some compiler warning.

Comment: @AndersK. You are right. It is probably added to satisfy some compiler. As @R and @GMan pointed out, although it is a way to force a bool conversation, the _!!_ trick is not needed here. Because it is already in a bool context. I am clear about it now. Thanks.

Comment: '-' is negate; '!' is not. "negative" and "positive" do not apply here. Using incorrect terminology sows confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a way to cast an expression to bool. In C++ though, operator! can be overloaded. Another way for C/C++:

```
0 != (expr)
```

C++ only way:

```
static_cast<bool>(expr)
```

**[Edit]**
Thinking more about C++ operator overloading, it make sense to avoid using operators. Libraries like Boost.Spirit and Boost.Lambda use expression templates and lazy evaluation, so that expressions like `(expr) || call()` may behave not as expected. The most bullet proof version of that macro looks like this:

```
#define uassert(expr) if(expr) {} else { uasserted(...); }
```

Here, only conversion of `expr` to bool is used. The `else` branch is needed to protect from expressions like `uassert(x) else something_else();`.

Comment: Accept this answer, because @Maxim gave both of the explanation and further knowledge.

Comment: And now `uassert(expr)` is no longer an expression; it's a statement. This greatly restricts where you could use it. If you want to cast to `bool`, just cast to `bool`.

Comment: It is an assert expression, whose value is of type bool in debug build and void in release, I assume. Could you demonstrate how greatly it restricts the usage please?

Comment: It is not "an assert expression" since it consists of an `if-else` *statement*.

Answer (score 1):

It will just make sure that the expr part of the macro is converted to a bool.

Comment: @GMan, generally yes, but perhaps not. It's possible that there is no implicit conversion to `bool` but there's an overloaded negation.

Comment: @Steven: Someone who writes such a class is an idiot. Sorry, I don't base my practices off what someone dumb might possibly write.

Comment: @GMan: That may well be the case. Nonetheless, the distinction is built into the language.

Answer (score 1):

It is an idiom sometimes used in C++ for converting to a boolean type.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you showed us, the `!!` is utterly useless. However, in general it's used as a pre-C99 rough equivalent to casting to `_Bool`, i.e. 0 stays 0 and any other value becomes 1.

Comment: `!!` is not quite useless. `(expr) || uasserted(...)` may not work as expected in C++ if `||` is an overloaded operator. This is why (expr) must be explicitly cast to boolean first.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me why I hate languages with operator overloading (or at least ones where the operators that should have fixed definitions in terms of other operators can be overloaded).

Comment: @Maxim: Awful reasoning. Observe: `!!` may not work as expected in C++ if `!` is an overloaded operator. Your argument is self-defeating: yes, someone can be moronic with operators, you can't conveniently ignore they could do the same to your position. It's useless for any orthodox program, who cares about the unorthodox crap people write? Base your practices off *good* code, so you end up having *good* programming practices.