# What does double not (!!) used on a non-boolean variable do?

Tags: c++, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double Negation in C++ code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code)

I am working with production code where I have run across statements like this a few times:

```
Class.func(!!notABool);
```

The first couple of times I dismissed it as a `programmer quirk` (maybe to emphasize that it is a conditional statement rather than a number being passed into func?) but I have run across several statements that use the above and now I am wondering whether it actually makes a difference or not. In most cases `notABool` is a number(int, float, double... I have seen all 3) My initial guess was that it is akin to typing:

```
Class.func((bool)notABool);
```

but I am not entirely sure?

Comment: Waiting for the Donald Knuth quote in 5...4...3...

Comment: @jonsca: Doh! Searched for all other wordings except for negation. Agreed, that is a duplicate.

Comment: Not to worry.  I think the title of the duplicate is misleading, but it popped up on the "Related" list ---->

Comment: That looks like a really !!bad practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For primitive types, yes, it's essentially equivalent to:

```
!(notABool != 0)
```

which in turn is equivalent to:

```
(bool)notABool
```

For non-primitive types, it will be a compiler error, unless you've overloaded `operator!`, in which case, it might do anything.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, functionally it is exactly the same as doing `(bool) notABool`.

By definition, in C++ language the operand of `!` is implicitly converted to `bool` type, so `!!notABool` is really the same as `!! (bool) notABool`, i.e. the same as just `(bool) notABool`.

In C language the `!!` was a popular trick to "normalize" a non-1/0 value to 1/0 form. In C++ you can just do `(bool) notABool`. Or you can still use `!!notABool` if you so desire.

Answer (score 4):

It's a legacy idiom from C, where it meant "normalize to 0 or 1". I don't think there's a reason to use it in C++ other than habit.

Answer (score 1):

It's converting BOOL (define for int) to c++ bool. BOOL is a define that in some cases for true can contain different integer values. So for example BOOL a = (BOOL)1; and BOOL b =(BOOL)2; both pass check for true. But if you'll try to compare you'll find that a not equals b. But after conversion !!a equals !!b.

(bool)notABoo - is not akin, because you'll convert type of variable byte still'll have different values. !! converts not only type but in some cases values too.