# Idiomatic way to check for non-zero

Tags: c, if-statement, idioms

When I wish to check if a value is `0` in C, how is it idiomatically done?

- `if (!num)`
- `if (num == 0)`

Comment: Prefer `if(0 == num)` If you have to choose second over First.First is the best option though.

Comment: @Als `if(0 == num)`, the classic Yoda condition

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Q of personal Choice really.I prefer that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While this is a matter of taste, I find it pretty much depends on intention. If the value is to be used as a boolean, `!` is alright. If the value is counting something the equality makes more sense.

```
if (!isVisible) {...}
if (isVisible == 0) {...} // Intention not as clear as line above.

if (numberOfItems == 0) {...}
if (!numberOfItems) {...} // Intention not as clear as line above.
```

Answer (score 6):

I always prefer the second way:

```
if (num == 0)
```

As `num == 0` or `ptr == NULL` evaluates to a boolean which is the intent.  The Java compiler enforces this form, but C/C++ compilers don't.

The worst example of this would be:

```
if (!strcmp(str, "something"))
```

Which really disguises its intent as the `strcmp` family of functions don't return boolean, they return positive, zero, or negative (as pointed out by @JoachimPileborg).

However if the `int` is being used to represent a boolean type, which C does not have a builtin type for, then this form is OK:

```
if (!b)
```

But this can be made self documenting by creating a custom type:

```
typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0

bool b = true;
if (!b)
{
   ... etc
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` is a good example. I like that in Objective-C, Apple has provided an enum with `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedSame` and `NSOrderedDescending` which makes the intention more clear than -1, 0 and 1.

Comment: Regarding the `strcmp` case, the return value can actually be any positive or negative value, besides zero. Never compare against `1` or `-1`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Agreed; you'd use `< 0` , `== 0` or `> 0`.

Comment: Oh yuck! No! "As num == 0 or ptr == NULL evaluates to a boolean which is the intent. The Java compiler enforces this form, but C/C++ compilers don't." This question is tagged C. In C these operations do not evaluate to a boolean. They evaluate to 0 or 1, explicitly in the specification an __int__ 0 or 1.

Comment: @JamesGreenhalgh: So you prefer something like: `char *p = &something; if (p) { ... }` ?

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm not expressing any preference for idioms. I'm expressing a preference for accurate statements about the result of expressions. Equality and Comparison operators return an __int__ of value 0 or 1. This distinction is important in C99, where evaluation to boolean would imply a result of type _Bool.

Comment: @JamesGreenhalgh: Interesting; I'd never even heard of `_Bool` let alone used it.  You live and learn :)

Answer (score 3):

Whatever the others told you WITH AN EXCEPTION!

Don't do it with `float` and `double`. IEEE 754 `float`s/`double`s/`long double`s (the most commonly used) often don't contain exact values, so comparing them directly with `0` is foolish (or doing `if (!floatValue)`)

Example: http://ideone.com/PIUflA

```
float f = 0.3;
f -= 0.2;
f -= 0.1;

if (!f)
{
    printf("zero\n");
}
else
{
    printf("non zero\n");
}

if (f == 0)
{
    printf("zero\n");
}
else
{
    printf("non zero\n");
}
```

With unoptimized compilation **can** return (on ideone does)

```
non zero
non zero
```

(if you enable optimizations, the compiler could pre-compute some values in higher precision and round them to `0`)

Comment: But doesn't that have more to do with `0.1` not being representable in base 2?

Comment: @Paul Yes (and even `0.2` and `0.3`). But the "why" isn't really relevant. The important thing was `"Don't do it with float an double"`

Comment: The reason given is wrong.
"often don't contain exact values"
is not true: floating-point types contain exact values - but the result of a computation might not be what a person naively assumes.
If you assign a literal "0" to a float then it always will compare true to "0". and that is the same for -0 too as that compares as equal to +0.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the context. If the variable refers to a boolean value is better first choice. Otherwise, the second is better.

Comment: I was about to write exactly the same thing.

Comment: I think we've all written about the same ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's done however you want it to be done, in terms of your style. I don't see it as mattering as long as your consistent and it's clear on what you're trying to do, or if you do it in cases where it may flow better in an English sentence and may put emphasis on what your doing.

For sake of clarity I usually have `if (num == 0)`, since it takes less thinking to understand what I'm doing when I'm going over my code.

Answer (score 0):

`!!value` will work too if you want to check if value is non-zero.

`!value` evaluates to 1 when value=0 and 0 when value≠0.
The second `!` flips it, making `!!value` evaluate to 1 when value≠0 and 0 when value=0.

Comment: And is even a trick in C++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code

Comment: @xanatos: sure, the question was about C.

Answer (score 0):

We may argue which way is better, but idiomatic, though for what I can tell by other answers archaic, would be `if(!num)`.

Answer (score 0):

For the compiler, it does not matter, of course. For the human reader it does. Since both forms are used by other human beings, you should get used to them and recognise them. Personally, I prefer the shortest form, which takes less time (less tokens, especially parenthesis) to read and understand. Especially:

```
if (!ptr) {}
if (!strcmp(a,b)) {}
```

are easyer to read than

```
if (ptr != NULL) {}
if (strcmp(a,b) == 0) {}
if (0 == strcmp()) {}
```

The last form makes me physically sick.

Comment: I would enjoy reading "if (0 == strcmp())". Totally a personal choice :p-)