# What is meaning of !! in C -- and why is it needed?

Tags: c, equation, not-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double Negation in C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code)

While reading one code I read:

```
flush = ! !(flags & GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH);
```

I am not getting what does `!!` mean here .
what does this sentence do?

**EDIT:**

I got it its a **double-negative.** trick to convert non-bool data to bool

*But what is the need of that?* Here flush is bool then if you assign any non zero item to bool it will treat as 1 and zero item as 0 so whats benefit of doing this?

Comment: Maybe someone confused the logical NOT (`!`) with the bitwise NOT (`~`)?

Comment: but whats need of that??
here flush is bool then if you assign any non zero item to bool it will treat as 1 and zero iteam as 0 so whats benefit of doing this?

Comment: @Mr.32 It is used to check whether the `GST_SEEK_FLAGS_FLUSH` bit is set in the `flags` variable.

Comment: This might be a duplicate, but *not of that question*. That is C++, which has these funny extra data-types. This is C.

Comment: @Mr.32: Well bool wasn't always available. In C versions before c99 there was no `bool`. It was just an `int` which could have any number in it. So if `flush` would still be an int then the result of `(flag & GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH)` might have the values 0 or `GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH`. And `GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH` could be `1` but it could also be `4`. Now if you want to ensure that the result of that expression is either `0` or `1` while `flush` being an int you could either write `(flags & GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH) != 0` or what you have seen `!!(flags & GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a double-negative. It's a way of converting an otherwise-non-bool expression (such as `flags & GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH`) to a `bool`. I personally prefer:

`flush = (flags & GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH) != 0;`

Comment: but whats need of that??
here flush is bool then if you assign any non zero item to bool it will treat as 1 and zero iteam as 0 so whats benefit of doing this?

Comment: @Mr.32 Perhaps later on ... `if (1 == flush) { ... }`. Because sometimes "bool conditional checking" is done explicitly with assumptions (and we all know that assumptions... ;-), not implicitly like `if (flush) { ... }`. Also, `flush` could be used in an entirely different context where it *must* be 1/0 to reflect a valid value, so the previous was just one example. "Better safe than sorry", and being consistent will minimize the "sorry" later :)

Comment: Yep, it's just a guarantee that it's a legitimate bool value rather than just simply being a non-zero value. It obfuscates the code, though, so I agree that it looks like nonsense, hence why I prefer the version I posted. It correctly turns it into a bool, and it *looks* like the way the brain is expecting it.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add a little example for you that might clear things.

```
 main()
 {
 int i=10;
 printf("%d",!!i);
 }
```

Output is 1

Comment: but whats need of that??
here flush is bool then if you assign any non zero item to bool it will treat as 1 and zero iteam as 0 so whats benefit of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If `flush` is boolean variable, and you force some non-boolean value to it, some compiler will generate a warning *forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false'*. So it's safer to use double negation.

Answer (score 2):

Some compilers (like Visual Studio) will warn when coercing a non-boolean type to an int, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 10;
    bool y = x; // warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
    return 0;
}
```

The double-negation trick is one way of converting to bool and preventing this warning, however I would lean towards the `!= 0` check Jim Buck recommended for clarity.