# Why use two '!' operators on a boolean value?

Tags: c++, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double Negation in C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code)

When I scanned the Webkit source code, I found a strange use of the boolean "not" operator `!`:

```
BOOL enabled;
if (SUCCEEDED(sharedPreferences->continuousSpellCheckingEnabled(&enabled)))
    continuousSpellCheckingEnabled = !!enabled;
if (SUCCEEDED(sharedPreferences->grammarCheckingEnabled(&enabled)))
    grammarCheckingEnabled = !!enabled;
```

Why don't they use `enabled` directly instead of `!!enabled`?

Comment: Nothing here mentions it explicitly, but that `BOOL` is most likely an integer of some sort. Judging by `SUCCEEDED`, I presume winapi, in which it's `int`.

Answer (score 14):

It's a C++ trick to convert anything to `1` or `0`.

For example, `42` is logically `true`, but is not `1`, so applying `!!` to it, you turn it into `1`.

Answer (score 5):

It's meant to force a value to a boolean. So if the value is evaluating to something, you'll get true.

Answer (score 4):

It forces a true value to be exactly 1.

In a boolean context (`if (x)`, `while (x)`, `x ? a : b`, `for (; x; )`), a value which is `0` means false, while any other value means true.

If your function accepts a truth value, but you need exactly 1 there, `!!` is fine.

In other words, `!!x` is the same as `x ? 1 : 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably continuousSpellCheckingEnabled is of type bool. BOOL is defined as int, so:

```
continuousSpellCheckingEnabled = enabled;
```

issues a warning, while:

```
continuousSpellCheckingEnabled = !!enabled;
```

does not.

Comment: +1 for explaining *why* it might be necessary to convert to {0,1}

Answer (score 1):

> why don't they directly use "enabled"

Double negation only cancels out for boolean values (0 and 1) so `!!(0) == 0` for non-boolean values the value will be converted to boolean `!!(100) == 1`