# What is the purpose of using !! for Pointers in C Conditions?

Tags: c++, c, embedded

I have seen code which uses a double not (!!)  for checking a pointer.But I am not finding an advantage of using !! in the condition check.Can some one shed some light on the purpose and advantage of using it.

```
int *Ptr;
/* ... */
if(!!Ptr)
{
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: guarantees that conditional will evaluate either as 0 or 1.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code

Comment: Tldr it's unnecessary here, and a compiler like GCC optimizes everything away

Comment: It's a much dumber way of writing `if(Ptr != NULL)`.