# Does "!!" have a special meaning in GTM scripts?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I came across the following syntax in a GTM script and am not quite sure how it's supposed to work:

```
if(!!{{var1}} && !!{{var2}}){
    // . . . other code here 
}
```

Now, I can tell that the `{{}}` syntax is used to capture variable values, but I can't find any reference to the `!!` operator (if there is such a thing).

Does it represent something in GTM, or is it just sloppy programming and these `!!` can be removed? I should mention that there are many more `if` statements in this script and they all look sane. This is the only one that has these `!!`. Any ideas?

Comment: Related, although for a different language: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code (I don't know GMT so cannot be sure it is doing the same thing.)

Comment: @WillemRenzema If you don't know GTM why are you bothering? Does it make _any_ sense to draw parallels from a different language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not GTM script specific, it's a standard JavaScript practice to coerce objects to boolean. In JavaScript there are falsey values like null or undefined, etc. ([list here](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/javascript/falsy-values/)), these will be false after using !! (bang bang), otherwise, true.

Note that this is not a special operand, just ! (NOT) used twice to force the type to be boolean.

Here is a good article that explains it very well: https://medium.com/@edplatomail/js-double-bang-or-the-not-operator-part-40e55d089bf0

To answer your question, it is not sloppy programming, and should not be removed.