# Keyword for exclusive or in ruby?

Tags: ruby, boolean, xor

Does Ruby have a plain-English keyword for exclusive or, like they have "and" and "or"? If not, is this because exclusive or doesn't allow evaluation short-cutting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think shortcircuiting can sensibly apply to XOR: whatever the value of the first operand, the second needs to be examined.

Secondly, and, &&, or and || use shortcircuiting in all cases; the only difference between the "word" and "symbol" versions is precedence. I believe that `and` and `or` are present to provide the same function as perl has in lines like

```
process_without_error or die
```

I think the reason for not having a `xor` named function is probably that there's no point in a low-precedence operator in this case and that it's already a confusing enough situation!

Comment: I think that "no point in low precedence `xor` function" is not right. In Perl I was used to check two exclusive CGI parameters with something like `param1 xor param2`. Shame I need to do this in a more complicated way in Ruby.

Comment: Nowadays, I agree about `and` and `or` being control flow. Avdi has written about it well at http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/ (in fact, I linked to this question in the comments section of that blog post)

Answer (score 26):

No it doesn't, you can only use `^`.

Don't know why there isn't particularly, may just be because it isn't as commonly used.

Comment: `^` runs into problems with truthy values. I defined my own function:

Comment: I have just been hit by this. I am using ruby-prof to improve an algorithm, and I thought that simplifying some condition with a XOR would make it faster. But it's the other way around.

Answer (score 19):

I ran into an issue because the '^' operator acts bitwise on numbers,

```
true ^ 1
=> false

1 ^ true
TypeError: can't convert true into Integer
true ^ 1
```

so my workaround was:

`( !!a ^ !!b )` where the double-bang coerces them into booleans.

```
!!1 ^ !!true
=> false

!!1 ^ !!false
=> true
```

Comment: Interesting, but not hugely relevant to the question.

Comment: ++ Useful. I came here looking for XOR, but know how to do the opposite, that is, coerce a bool to_i? My other operand is already an int, and I need the result to be int.

Comment: @Macha +1ing because I've just come across the same issue, and there's no other questions about Ruby boolean xors that weren't about strings.

Comment: Since basically you are checking that the values are different, you can actually save a `!` and just do: `!foo ^ !bar`. Or `!foo != !bar`

Comment: In fact you only need first value to be a boolean. `!!var1 ^ var2`. Also `nil` has the `^` operator working as a boolean xor.

Answer (score 14):

Try `^`

```
true  ^ false #=> true
true  ^ true  #=> false
false ^ false #=> false
```

No plain english equivalent operator though.

Comment: my issue with this is `true ^ true ^ true` => `true`

Comment: @MrYoshiji It makes sense if the order of operations is (true ^ true) ^ true. The parenthesis evaluates to false, giving you false ^ true, which in the end is true.

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to Matt Van Horn's double negation trick for using XOR on arbitrary types, you can chain another XOR test, starting with `nil`.  i.e.:

```
!!foo ^ !!bar
```

is equivalent to

```
nil ^ foo ^ bar
```

This looks neater to my eye, and I suppose requires one less logical operation

Answer (score 2):

Any implementation of `xor` won't allow short circuiting. Both expressions need to be evaluated no matter what.

Ruby does provide the `^` operator, but this will choke on truthy values. I've implemented a function to handle the cases where I want an `xor` that behaves more like `and` and `or`:

```
def xor(a,b)
  (a and (not b)) or ((not a) and b)
end
```

Unlike `^`, this function can be used in situations similar to the following:

```
xor("hello".match(/llo/), false) # => true
xor(nil, 1239)                   # => true
xor("cupcake", false)            # => false
```

Comment: Chris Phoenix's answer/comment about `xor("cupcake", false)` returning true is correct.

Answer (score 2):

John's answer appears incorrect. In irb with 1.9.3, xor("cupcake", false) returns true, as you'd expect.

```
1.9.3-p429 :104 > def xor(a,b)
1.9.3-p429 :105?>     (a and (not b)) or ((not a) and b)
1.9.3-p429 :106?>   end
 => nil 
1.9.3-p429 :107 > xor(false, true)
 => true 
1.9.3-p429 :108 > xor("cupcake", false)
 => true
```