# Separate date and time form fields in Rails

Tags: datetime, forms, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an ActiveRecord model `Event`with a datetime column `starts_at`. I would like to present a form, where date and time for `starts_at` are chosen separately (e.g. `"23-10-2010"` for date and `"18:00"` for time). These fields should be backed by the single column `starts_at`, and validations should preferably be against `starts_at`, too.

I can of course muck around with virtual attributes and hooks, but I would like a more elegant solution. I have experimented with both `composed_of` ([rdoc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html)), and attribute-decorator ([lighthouse discussion](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/950-attributedecorator-a-new-take-on-aggregation), [github](http://github.com/Fingertips/attribute-decorator)) without success.

Below is a rough outline of what I would like..

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :start_date
end

# View
# On submission this should set start_date.
form_for @event do |f|
  f.text_field :starts_at_date         # date-part of start_date
  f.text_field :starts_at_time_of_day  # time-of-day-part of start_date
  f.submit
end
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I've run into this a few times now but still haven't found a nice solution. The reason for splitting it up is so I can use a datepicker and the time_select separately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Was looking at this today for a Rails project, and came across this gem:

https://github.com/shekibobo/time_splitter

> Setting DateTimes can be a difficult or ugly thing, especially through a web form. Finding a good DatePicker or TimePicker is easy, but getting them to work on both can be difficult. TimeSplitter automatically generates accessors for date, time, hour, and min on your datetime or time attributes, making it trivial to use different form inputs to set different parts of a datetime field.

Looks like it would do the job for you

Comment: Is there a way of setting timezone for this gem? It always saves in UTC.

Comment: In my testing it was using the configured time zone. Are you sure you were setting it correctly?

Comment: I tried to use this gem and ran into a problem right away http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858627/time-splitter-gem-getting-uninitialized-constant-sheettimesplitter

Answer (score 39):

Do you have to have a `text_field` in the view?

As far as I can tell, you can have a `date_time` field and then just use two different input fields to set the different parts of the field.

```
form_for @event do |f|
  f.date_select :starts_at
  f.time_select :starts_at, :ignore_date => true
  f.submit
end
```

Since the rails date and time select helpers set five different parameters (`starts_at(1i)` for the year part, `2i` for the month part, and so on), that means that the `date_select` only sets them for the date part, while if you pass `:ignore_date => true` to the `time_select`, it will only set the hour and minute part.

If you must have a `text_field` I'm not sure how to do it, but it might be possible to do using some jQuery magic before setting the datetime parameters before sending the form.

Comment: Nice, seems to work and a good enough of a solution. But what I'd really like to see is a way to divide and reconstruct attributes around the form helper. E.g. before_form_build & before_form_validation.

Comment: Then I think you'd need to do some manual hacking on the params hash.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `date_select` and `time_select` is a good way to go.

However, I wanted a `text_field` for the date (so I can use a JavaScript date picker).

Using strong_parameters or Rails 4+:

*models/event.rb*

```
# Add a virtual attribute
attr_accessor :start_at_date
```

*views/events/_form.html.haml*

```
- # A text field for the date, and time_select for time
= f.label :start_at
= f.text_field :start_at_date, value: (f.object.start_at.present? ? f.object.start_at.to_date : nil)
= f.time_select :start_at, :ignore_date => true
```

*controllers/events_controller.rb*

```
# If using a date_select, time_select, datetime_select
# Rails expects multiparameter attributes
# Convert the date to the muiltiparameter parts
def event_params
  if !!params[:event] && (params[:event]["start_at(4i)"].present? || params[:event]["start_at(5i)"].present?)

    if params[:event][:start_at_date].present?
      start_at_date = params[:event][:start_at_date]
    else
      start_at_date = Date.today
    end
    year  = start_at_date.match(/^(\d{4})[\-\/]/)[1]
    month = start_at_date.match(/[\-\/](\d{2})[\-\/]/)[1]
    day   = start_at_date.match(/[\-\/](\d{2})$/)[1]
    params[:event]["start_at(1i)"] = year
    params[:event]["start_at(2i)"] = month
    params[:event]["start_at(3i)"] = day
  end
  ...
```

Comment: Why do you use `!!` in the ***if*** comparison? What does that means?

Comment: Converts the value into a boolean (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524658/what-does-mean-in-ruby), probably not required.

Comment: Yeah thats what I though but anyway thank you for the response. :)

Answer (score 2):

Elegant solution may provide [**date_time_attribute** gem](https://github.com/einzige/date_time_attribute):

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include DateTimeAttribute

  date_time_attribute :starts_at
end
```

It will allow you to set `starts_at_date` and `starts_at_time` separately:

```
form_for @event do |f|
  f.text_field :starts_at_date
  f.text_field :starts_at_time
  f.submit
end

# this will work too:
form_for @event do |f|
  f.date_select :starts_at_date
  f.time_select :starts_at_time, :ignore_date => true
  f.text_field  :starts_at_time_zone
  f.submit
end

# or
form_for @event do |f|
  f.date_select :starts_at_date
  f.text_field  :starts_at_time
  f.submit
end
```

It will also allow you to play with time zones, use Chronic etc.

Comment: Are you sure you can mix `date_select` and `text_field`?  I wasn't able to use a `text_field` and `time_select` and there is no documentation showing you can.

Comment: You don't need to include the DateTimeAttribute module, as said in the README of the repository of the gem: https://github.com/einzige/date_time_attribute#rails-users

Answer (score 0):

Is this because of a design issue? It is really much easier if you just save starts_at as a datetime data type and use something like:

http://puna.net.nz/timepicker.htm#

It simply runs on top of whatever date fields you have for your model.

Comment: No it's not a design issue. The data should be a single column while the form builder should handle 2 different attributes for that same column.