# How to implicitly convert Ruby object to boolean

Tags: ruby

Can be some method added to Ruby object to achieve automatic conversion to boolean? E.g. `if obj == true`

Comment: What are the rules for the conversion? Which objects should be converted to `true` and which to `false`?

Comment: "Double bang" is usually used for this (`!!obj`). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994033/ruby-operator-a-k-a-the-double-bang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` is a syntax sugar for `:==` method. You can define object's own `:==` method, where you can specify, based on internal object's state, when the result of the comparision should be `true` and when `false`:

```
class SomeClass
  def ==(val)
    # specyfy the comparision behaviour
  end
end
```

And then use it like:

```
sc = SomeClass.new
sc == true
=> true # or false, depending on :== method's implementation
```

Comment: One can also use `to_bool` method.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, you are going to check the truthyness of an object instead of converting it to a boolean explicitly. This is what happens of you just write

```
if obj
  # here, obj is truethy
else
  # here, object is falsey
end
```

In Ruby, only `false` and `nil` are defined as falsey. All other objects are truethy. This can be used in conditions as shown above. Because of this, an explicit check for `true` or `false` is rather rare in Ruby.

That said, if you do want to convert an object to a boolean based on its truthyness value, you can use the double-negation, i.e.

```
obj_truthyness = !!obj
# => true or false
```

Comment: Thank you, but i want to implicitly convert object which is not nil. Boolean value depends on the internal state of the object and explicit conversion cannot be done (due to SASS).

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Please edit your original question and add some details to describe (1) what exactly you want to achieve, with actual examples (2) where this should be used and (3) why you need this.