# What is the !! and a few other things in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have been digging through some ruby gem code and i came across these and not sure what they means

```
def success?
  !!@success
end

def failure?
  !@success
end

cattr_accessor :test_response
```

and lastly this chunk of code

```
class_inheritable_accessor :attributes
self.attributes = []

def self.attribute(name, options={})
  top_level_name = name.to_s.split(".").last.underscore
  define_method top_level_name do
    read_attribute name
  end
```

If you only know one or two thats fine ...i just want to understand them...thanks

Comment: For the benefit of googling, `!` is called the bang operator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does !! mean in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524658/what-does-mean-in-ruby)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`!!` is a "cast to boolean". `!` negates a value, `!!` negates the negated value. Hence `!!` turns any value into a boolean.

```
> 5
=> 5
> !5
=> false
> !!5
=> true
> !!5 == true
=> true
```

Comment: Wouldn't just '!' be the 'cast to boolean', "!!" just negated the first '!' ( which casts the value to boolean )

Comment: @Rishav "cast to boolean" as in "cast to *equivalent* boolean value". Not sure if `!` could be called a cast, since the value is completely opposite. That's putting a really fine point on it though.

Comment: @Rishav: if `@@success` is a string, `x = 'TRUE';!!x;` would yield `true` instead of `'TRUE'`. The `!@success` would return `false` but issue a warning.

Answer (score 3):

What parts specifically don't you understand in the second part of code?

The methods `success?` and `failure?` in the first snippet return boolean values (true/false) in relation to the `@success` instance attribute.

`cattr_accessor` creates a read/write class attribute called `test_response`

Here's a little more information which is also explained better: http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor