# What does !!some_object do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does !! mean in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524658/what-does-mean-in-ruby)

what is this function doing?

```
def current_product?
   !!current_product
end
```

Isn't that a double negative?

Comment: Duplicate of [What does !! mean in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524658/what-does-mean-in-ruby).

Comment: The same, as in other languages...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!!` is basically a cast to boolean. If `current_product` is *truthy*, `!current_product` is `false` and `!!current_product` is `true`, and vice versa. I.e. it converts *truthy* values to `true` and *falsy* values to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

It's effectively a cast/conversion to boolean.

Similar question, but for C++: [Doube Negation in C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248693/double-negation-in-c-code)

Also a pretty decent post about it here: [!! (The double bang / double not) in Ruby](http://www.themomorohoax.com/2008/12/09/the-double-bang-double-exclamation-points-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pattern you'll see in any language where every object has a truth value, but there are *canonical* booleans (whether they be called `True` and `False`, `1` and `0`, `1` and `""`, `t` and `nil`, whatever). `!!x` is essentially a "cast to boolean", in that `!!x` has the same truth-value as `x`, but `!!x` will always be one of the canonical true/false values, instead of any old true/false value.