# Ruby boolean double negation convention

Tags: ruby

Can anybody tell me why a lot of Ruby boolean methods use this double negation convention?

```
!!(boolean expression)
```

Comment: Not a rubyist, but i would imagine to coerce the value to boolean?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524658/what-does-mean-in-ruby

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The double negation ensures that no matter the initial value, you will always get `true` or `false`, never some mystery value.

This is handy because it avoids dangling references to objects you no longer require, or having to differentiate between two types of false value, `nil` and `false`.

Often you will see methods written like this:

```
def logged_in?
  !!@session_user
end
```

This will return `true` or `false` and that value can be used for whatever purpose is required. Compare that with this:

```
def logged_in?
  @session_user
end
```

In this case if you save the value, you're actually saving the whole `@session_user` object, which could be a fairly significant chunk of memory. This memory cannot be released until your reference to it falls out of scope. Since there is only one `true` and one `false`, there's no need for garbage collection.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you want to define a method that returns a boolean. For example, whether a string matches a regex.

```
class String
  def include? regex; self =~ regex end
end
```

If you do the above, it will return `nil` when it does not match, and an integer when it matches. In many cases, that does not matter so much (`nil` is similar to `false` and `true` can be substituted for an integer). But if you really wanted a boolean as a return value, if you do

```
class String
  def include? regex; !!(self =~ regex) end
end
```

it will return `true` when it matches, `false` when it does not.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Ruby is just a little too clever about Booleans. This is a workaround for the cases when the cleverness causes problems.

Here's the excessive cleverness: there's no Boolean class. Instead, there's a convention under which *any* value can serve as a boolean. In a context where a true-or-false value is required, `nil` or `false` means "false" and anything else means "true". The values `true` and `false` are not part of a special class, they're the sole members of their respective classes — they exist only to make code a little more readable.

I guess this works fine most of the time, but every once in a very long while you need a boolean value that is *always* `true` or `false`. For example, I recently needed to compare two boolean values and do something special if they were different; the only problem being, one of them was either `true` or `false`, while the other was either 1 or `nil`. Fix? Utilize the fact that `!!nil == false` and `!!1 == true`.