# Could you explain what's !! do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does !! mean in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524658/what-does-mean-in-ruby)

I found !! in Paypal gem here: https://github.com/tc/paypal_adaptive/blob/master/lib/paypal_adaptive/config.rb
like 59

but I don't understand what it does.

I know that ! means NOT, but !! doesn't make sense.

here's the screen: http://tinyurl.com/7acklhr

Comment: If you know what `!(foo)` means then you should be able to work out what `!(!(foo))` means :) It's not a different operator, just the same operator applied twice

Comment: You might try Googling "ruby double bang"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used to make sure its the boolean type.

[Explanation more detailed](http://www.themomorohoax.com/2008/12/09/the-double-bang-double-exclamation-points-in-ruby)

Eg:

> > !!active
> >     => true
> >
> > active = false
> >     => false
> >
> > !!active
> >     => false
> >
> > active = nil
> >     => nil
> >
> > !!active
> >     => false

Answer (score 4):

It forces any value to `true` or `false` depending on its "truthy" nature.

This is simply because, as you've noted, `!` is the Boolean-not operator. For instance:

```
t = 1
puts !t  # => false
puts !!t # => true
f = nil
puts !f  # => true
puts !!f # => false
```

Answer (score 4):

The `!!` is used to return either `true` or `false` on something that returns anything :

In Ruby, everything other than `nil` and `false` is interpreted as `true`. But it will not return true, it will return the value.
So if you use `!`, you get `true` or `false` but the opposite value of what is really is.
If you use `!!`, you get the `true` or `false` corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

This forces a result to be true or false. As in ruby nil is not exactly false this can be useful. For instance:

```
def try x
  if x == 1
    return nil
  else
    return "non-nil"
  end
end

p "try1" if try(1) # here you get a string printed
p "try2" if !!try(1) # here you don't
```