# Whats the ruby !! operator?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does !! mean in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524658/what-does-mean-in-ruby)

I'm learning ruby/rails and found a tutorial with the following code example:

```
def role?(role)
    return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
end
```

I don't have any idea for what the `!!` do, neither the `!!self` do.

I really googled about that, but doesn't find anything.

Can anyone give a short explanation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://symbolhound.com/?q=%21%21+ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the "not" operator (`!`) repeated twice, so that it's argument will be coerced to its negated boolean and then its corresponding boolean.  Basically, it's a way to coerce any object into its boolean value.

```ruby
!!false # => false
!!nil # => false
!!true # => true
!!{} # => true
!![] # => true
!!1 # => true
!!0 # => true (Surprised? Only 'false' and 'nil' are false in Ruby!)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's usually employed to force-cast an arbitrary value into one of `true` or `false`.
This is often useful for converting between arbitrary numbers, strings, or potential `nil` values.

In your example this is extremely inefficient since an entire model is loaded only to be discarded. It would be better written as:

```
def role?(role)
  self.roles.count_by_name(role.to_s.camelize) > 0
end
```

That query will return a singular value that is used for comparison purposes, the result of which is automatically a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

This confirms that the operation will always return the boolena value

```
!!1 #gives you true
!!nil #gives you false
```

In ruby nil, false is consider as false and 0, 0.0 and other objects are consider as true