# Shortcut for if..else..end

Tags: ruby, if-statement

Are there any kind of shortcut for code like this?

```
def test
  obj = get_from_somewhere()
  if obj
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

In Python, I can do like this:

```
return True if obj else False
```

Comment: Just `obj` unless you need an actual Boolean, or !!obj. Or use a ternary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A common Ruby idiom to achieve this is:

```
def test
  !!get_from_somewhere
end
```

The [double bang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524658/what-does-mean-in-ruby) turns an object into its "boolean equivalent":

```
object = 'foo'
!object
# => false
!!object
# => true
```

Pay attention that in Ruby, unlike Python, just `false` and `nil` evaluates to false in boolean context, for example:

```
!!0
# => true
```

Comment: Just don't forget to add a link to [What does !! mean in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524658/what-does-mean-in-ruby) when using this outside your personal projects ;)

Answer (score 7):

The ! is the not/negate operator.  It turns the object into a Boolean variable that is the negative of its value.  So, if test = 1, then !test is false because test is true.  (Any value that is not false or nil is true.)

Using !! is not a specific operator, it is just ! twice.  So, if a value is neither false nor nil, then !! returns  true.

That being said, a more obvious way of writing the expression nearly equivalent to PHP is the ternary operator:

```
def test
  obj = get_from_somewhere()
  obj ? true : false  # Returns true as long as obj is neither false nor nil.
end
```

Or, even more simply if you don't need the obj variable:

```
def test
  get_from_somewhere() ? true : false  # Returns true as long as get_from_somewhere() is neither false nor nil.
end
```

Comment: +1 because this is a more general answer, for the case when the return value of `test` is not boolean.

Comment: @SonySantos So was the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
obj ? true : false
```