# Rails authentication from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

Actually I am new to rails I was trying to build authentication from scratch but didn't have any idea. So I was reading some code on internet and I am struck at a function.What does !! means over here. Is it first making it false then true? What it is and why we are using it?

```
def logged_in?
  !!current_user
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does !! mean in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524658/what-does-mean-in-ruby)

Comment: the link was not helpful

Comment: You can either use `current_user` or `!current_user`

Comment: `current_user` returns either an user object or `nil`, but we want `true` or `false`. `!!` does it.

Comment: The second most upvoted answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/524688/1235795) even uses the same code snippet as you do. So I really don't get why it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: It is. `!!current_user` will look up if the var `current_user` is an filled object / string / whatever. If yes it's `true`, if not it returns `false`. So the value for `logged_in` is `false` if `current_user` is not a string or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!` means "not", so `!!` means "not-not".  `!` is often called "bang" (because 'exclamation mark' is too long, i assume) and so `!!` is often called "double bang".  See also "hashbang" or "shebang" which mean `#!`.

It has the effect of converting all "truthy"* things into the boolean `true` and all "falsy" things  into the boolean `false`.

Note that in Ruby, unlike some languages, the only things that are "falsy" are `false` and `nil`.  0, "", [], {}, and any other object that isn't false or nil, such as a User object, are "truthy".

*"truthy" means it will pass an "if" test.

Answer (score 0):

We use double bang to get value as Boolean (true/false). Here is demonstration:

```
2.1.2 :001 > my_var = "string"
 => "string" 
2.1.2 :002 > !my_var
 => false 
2.1.2 :003 > !!my_var
 => true

2.1.2 :005 > null_var = nil
 => nil 
2.1.2 :006 > !!null_var
 => false
```

So, as you can see that, if we want to get corresponding boolean value for an object then we use double bang (`!!`).

In your case, I assume `current_user` can have `user` object OR `nil` value. Instead of getting `user` object or `nil`, it's using `!!` to convert it into corresponding boolean.

Hope it helps. Happy Learning!

**EDIT:**
I would like to add that in Ruby, it's convention that method name ending with `?` will return boolean value. So, your mentioned code us using `!!` in `logged_in?` to return boolean instead of `User` or `NULL` class objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do something like this

```
def logged_in?
  current_user
```

you are asking here if it is a current user

```
def logged_in?
  !current_user
```

while you are asking here is the logged in user is not current_user.