# How can I fix an int-to-bool warning in C++?

Tags: c++, integer, boolean

I get a warning in MSVC++ when I try to read an integer from a file and make a bool variable equal it.

```
accessLV[i] = FileRead(file1, i + 1);
```

(accessLV is an array of bools, FileRead is a function I made to decrease the syntax involved in reading from a file, i is because the statement is within a for loop)

I've tried using a static_cast:

```
accessLV[i] = static_cast<bool>(FileRead(file1, i + 1));
```

But I still get the warning.  I've tried doing this (I'm not sure the exact term):

```
accessLV[i] = (bool)FileRead(file1, i + 1));
```

And the warning is still there.  Is there anyway to get rid of the warning without making accessLV an array of ints?

NB:  this is the syntax of FileRead, if it helps:

```
int FileRead(std::fstream& file, int pos)
{
    int data;
    file.seekg(file.beg + pos * sizeof(int));
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof(data));
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
accessLV[i] = FileRead(file1, i + 1) != 0;
```

Comment: An extra set of ( ) wouldn't go astray there just to show where the precedence is!

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is basically

accessLV[i] = (FileRead(file1, i + 1) != 0)

Answer (score 2):

```
accessLV[i] = FileRead(file1, i + 1) != 0;
```

Above, you were casting from int to bool: if you use this, the result of the comparison is put in accessLV[i], so not type warnings occur.

Answer (score 2):

As other posters have suggested, `!=0` is what you need.  I prefer a wrapper like this because I find it more readable:

```
// myutil.hpp
template< typename T >
inline bool bool_cast( const T & t ) { return t != 0; }
```

Which you would use in this case like this:

```
// yourcode.cpp
accessLV[ i ] = bool_cast( FileRead( file1, i + 1 ) );
```

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206106/is-a-safe-way-to-convert-to-bool-in-c) has additional discussion you might find useful.