# PHP converting to boolean using '!!'

Tags: php, boolean

Fairly straight-forward question here. Been looking over some code and I've seen a function that seems to convert a given variable to a boolean. It goes like this:

```
function to_bool( $var ) {
    return !!$var;
}
```

Pretty simple, but how does it work? Never seen this before, and googling hasn't really gotten me anywhere. Does the extra '!' sort-of flip the result? '!$var' can be used to check if a var is false, so does '!!' turn a 'false' to true, and vice versa?

Comment: you did mean `(bool)$var;` because i have never seen that before the two !! before a variable

Comment: `!` negates, so two double negates, converting whatever it is to boolean...

Comment: Double negatives, was thinking that. Very odd. Is it completely reliable do you think?

Comment: This construct is more common in other languages.  [Apparently this is one way to cast to bool in C++ without generating a compiler warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206106/is-a-safe-way-to-convert-to-bool-in-c). -- in fact, this practice may have arisen from C not having a native bool type until C99 (?)

Comment: so, what would an appropiate value for `$var` be? i'm trying to understand why id need to do this

Comment: I really recommend not using a function for this.  `(bool)$var` where-ever you need it is much cleaner, and doesn't require a library function to avoid a fatal error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> how does it work?

The not operator places the variable into a conditional. Therefore, the result is boolean. The second not flips its value.

It's more clear just to use an explicit cast in your code rather than such a function:

```
(bool)$var;
```

Comment: To be pedantic, it's the second 'not' in temporal sequence, or the first 'not' in physical sequence, that flips the value.

Comment: @Seth: Right. That's how I meant it.

Answer (score 3):

One `!` would be an inverted boolean so two `!!` make a non-inverted boolean. It's a double negation of a variable and returned as a boolean type

Answer (score 3):

Take !!2

`!2` evaluates to `!(true)`

which evaluates to `!false` end result `true`. The not boolean basically treats the right operand as a bool.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... interesting.

Well, PHP follows a specific set of rules when determining whether a variable is "true" or "false".

Using certain operators will force that decision to be made. For example, when you add a string `"a"` and an integer `2` with the `.` operator, you'd get `"a2"`, because the `.` operator's intent is to concatenate.

Here, the first `!` means you're attempting to negate the variable. To negate anything means that you must first be treating it as a boolean, so that's what it does. Then the second `!` just negates it back.

It's a weird way of doing it. Frankly, `if ($var)` would yield the same result as your `if (to_bool($var))`.

Comment: Do you think '!!$var' would be a quicker method of checking that 'to_bool($var)'? Just out of curiousity really! Obviously a pretty negligible difference if any!

Comment: `if($var)` is the fastest, but yes, the difference would be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at this from the perspective of type conversion. In PHP, performing a logical expression on a value will give a boolean result.  So, the first negation implicitly casts the value as a bool, and the second-evaluated is just to reverse the negation of the first one.  You can do the same thing using other logical operators (although I wouldn't recommend it, as some have different precedence):

```
// using "truthy" 2 as a value //

!!2          // true 
2 ||  false  // true
2 &&  true   // true
2 xor false  // true

// using "falsey" 0 as a value //

!!0         // false
0 ||  false // false
0 &&  true  // false
0 xor false // false
```